PySpark Elasticsearch connector: relationship between es.write.operation and dataframe SaveMode?
I want to upsert data to Elasticsearch and wrote the following code.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Create Spark client
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .appName("preferences") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create example DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=1, a=2),
    Row(id=2, a=3),
    Row(id=4, a=5)
])

# Redacted these values
elasticsearch_port = 443
elasticsearch_user = "elastic"
elasticsearch_password = "..."
elasticsearch_endpoint = "https://..."

# Write the data to Elasticsearch
df.write.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql') \
    .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true") \
    .option('es.nodes', elasticsearch_endpoint) \
    .option('es.port', elasticsearch_port) \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.user", elasticsearch_user) \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", elasticsearch_password) \
    .option("es.resource", 'debug_example') \
    .option("es.mapping.id", 'id') \
    .option("es.write.operation", "upsert") \
    .save()

Despite setting .option("es.write.operation", "upsert"), the df.write command fails if I run it a second time with the error:

org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: SaveMode is set to ErrorIfExists and index debug_example exists and contains data. Consider changing the SaveMode

Shouldn't es.write.operation take precedent over the Data Frame's SaveMode? Perhaps my es.write.operation setting is not taking effect for some reason? I can make this error go away if I set mode("append") or mode("ignore"), but I want to make sure I'm not glossing over an important distinction.
The SaveMode docs and Elasticsearch connector docs don't clarify the difference. I'm using Spark 3.4.0 and the elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-8.13.2.jar connector.
